# test if object is in an array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, object, textfield

I know I'm overlooking something easy, but I am using

```
if (textField == self.nameTextField || textField == self.ageTextField || textField == ...)
```

when ideally I'd like to use something that allows the textField to be compared to an array of allowed (named) textField objects.

I've tried to pseudocode what I think the solution would look like a couple of times, I just don't know what I'm doing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check like:

```
if([textFieldArray containsObject:textField])
{
     //do stuff here
}
```

Here `textFieldArray` is the `array` which holds all `textFields`.

If the `textField` object is in the `textFieldArray`, it'll return `true`.

Comment: I knew it would be easy. Tried and tested. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: no probs. I was inside the 15 minute blockout of answer acceptance, so I couldn't. But gladly done now. Thanks again. I'd even upvote it, but I have no reps yet...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add all references of `UITextFields` in `NSArray`.

Now use `containsObject` in `NSArray` to `check` if `exists`

```
BOOL contains = [yourArrayofTextFields containsObject:textField];
if(contains)
  // contains
else
  // not contains
```

Comment: Thanks Prince, Midhun pipped you at the post, although they're pretty much the same. "containsObject" is exactly what I was after.